# Cannot set virtual host

Tags: apache, virtualhost, wampserver, vhosts

Lately I'm not able to create a virtual hosts on my machine except for .localhost which is the only extension works for me now.

I'm using Wampserver which takes care of editing the **hosts** and **httpd.vhosts** files

I've tried **.local** and **.test** and **.app** but every time I try to access those domain I get

> This site can’t be reached
>   server DNS address could not be found.

As i said except for **.localhost** which works fine.

Anyone have any suggestion on how to solve this problem

Thanks in advance.

**httpd-vhosts.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName flashy.app
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/projects/packages/flashy/public"
        <Directory  "c:/wamp/www/projects/packages/flashy/public/">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**hosts**

```
127.0.0.1   flashy.app
::1 flashy.app
```

Comment: Show us your `httpd-vhosts.conf` file and your `hosts` file

Comment: @RiggsFolly i've edited my post